# Styling the contents within a CSS lable

Tags: css, label

Can any one tell me why my label styling via class of a label tag is only working when I first define a style via id?

Here's my examples:

Why does this work to turn the border green:
http://jsfiddle.net/HxrSU/13/

Yet this does not when I remove the styling via ID?
http://jsfiddle.net/HxrSU/14/

Here's the full code, the code from http://jsfiddle.net/HxrSU/13/

```
<style type="text/css">
#red {
border: thick dotted red;    
} 

.label-for-check {
border: thick solid green;
}
</style>   

<input type="checkbox" id="check" class="check-with-label" />

<label for="check" id="red" class="label-for-check">
 MyField
<input type='text' id='myfield' name='myfield' size='10'  />
</label>
```

Comment: You mustn't put `<style>` tags within `CSS` windows on jsFiddle. Without them your code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/HxrSU/15/ and http://jsfiddle.net/HxrSU/14/

Comment: For "teach a man to fish" advice, I'd suggest using the TidyUp button. It points out that sort of thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS statements on IDs are higher in precedence (specificity) than those for classes.

Read more: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

One way to override the ID statement with your class statement would be to include an ID from a mutual ancestor:

http://jsfiddle.net/HxrSU/25/

```
#page .label-for-check {
    border: thick solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the labels to be same the do following

```
label {
border:5px solid red;  
 }
```

If you want to further specialize a specific one then use classes or ids.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
.label-for-check {
border: thick solid green;
}
```

To:

```
label.label-for-check {
border: thick solid green;
}
```

and it will work fine.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/2SFbY/